# remove event listener with event and parameters within class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a class which will handle the ajax request of symfony form type, and will handle the response.

I have a MutationObserver which read all changes in the DOM and add a new listener to the new forms again. I need to addEventListener and removeEventListeners all times except the last one because of the event listener save several events in each form of the DOM.

The issue is removeEventListener is not working. I know the methods addEventListener and removeEventListener shoud be the same and I think the problem is the anonymous function of sendAsyncForm, but I can't solve it because I need to pass the event and the parameters. I've tried this through diferents ways, nonetheless I have achieved to pass either the event, or the parameters, but not both.

I can't see the solution.

My code is the following:

```html
<table class="table" id="admin__table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>CreationDate</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for admin in admins %}
        <tr {% if not admin.isActive %}style="background-color: #ffaaaa;"{% endif %}>
            <td>{{ admin.id }}</td>
            <td>
                {% set showPath = path('app_admin_show', {'id': admin.id}) %}
                <div class="text-primary" data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#crudModal" type="button" onclick="asyncHTML('{{ showPath }}', 'crud-modal__body')">
                    {{ admin.name }} {{ admin.firstname }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ admin.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ admin.roles ? admin.roles|json_encode : '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ admin.creationDate ? admin.creationDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '' }}</td>
            <td>
                <div data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#crudModal">
                    {% include "components/admin/triggers/admin_edit-button.html.twig" with {'path': path('app_admin_edit', {'id': admin.id}), 'HTMLPlaceDOMelementId': 'crud-modal__body'} %}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{% include "admin/_block_form.html.twig" %}</td>
            <td>{% include "admin/_delete_form.html.twig" %}</td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">no records found</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    blockFormObserver();

    function blockFormObserver() {
        let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
            let forms = document.querySelectorAll("form[async][name='admin__block']");
            let asyncFormArray = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                asyncFormArray[i] = new AsyncForm(forms[i]);

                asyncFormArray[i].setResponse(function() {response => console.log("response")});
                asyncFormArray[i].setOnsuccess(() => asyncHTML("{{ path('app_admin_index') }}", "admin__index"));

                asyncFormArray[i].prepare();
                if (i < forms.length-1) asyncFormArray[i].remove();
            }
        });

        // define what element should be observed by the observer
        // and what types of mutations trigger the callback
        observer.observe(document, {
            subtree: true,
            attributes: true,
        });
    }
</script>
```

```js
class AsyncForm {
    constructor(form) {
        if (form == null) throw new AsyncFormException('Form passed to constructor is null', this.form);
        if (form.getAttribute("action") == null) throw new AsyncFormException('Action attribute wasn`t found', this.form);

        this.form = form;
        this.action = this.form.getAttribute("action");
        // this.method ? form.getAttribute("method") : null;
        this.previous = false;
        this.response = false;
        this.onsuccess = false;
    }

    prepare() {
        this.form.addEventListener("submit", this.sendAsyncForm(this.response, this.onsuccess));
    }

    remove() {
        this.form.removeEventListener("submit", this.sendAsyncForm(this.response, this.onsuccess));
    }

    sendAsyncForm(response, onsuccess) {
        return (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log(response);
    
            // if (this.previous) {
            //     try {
            //         this.previous();
            //     } catch {
            //         return false;
            //     }
            // }
    
            var formData = new FormData(this.form);
    
            // loader("crud-modal__body");
    
            $.ajax({
                url : this.action,
                type : 'POST',
                data : formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType : 'html',
                success : response => {
                    // if (this.response) this.response(response);
                    if (this.onsuccess) this.onsuccess();
                },
                error : (xhr, status) => {
                    if (xhr.status = 422) this.response(xhr.responseText);
                    else response("<div class='form-error'>Ocurrió un problema al enviar el formulario, disculpe las molestias.</div>");
                },
            });
        }
    }

    setAction(action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    // set method(method) {
    //     this.method = method;
    // }

    setPrevious(previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    setResponse(response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    setOnsuccess(onsuccess) {
        this.onsuccess = onsuccess;
    }

}

function AsyncFormException(message, form) {
    this.message = message;
    this.form = form;
    this.name = "AsyncFormException";
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 2nd argument to `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` needs to be a function, not a call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to bind and reference your callback and params, then pass it to the event listener.

Check more info about `bind` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```js
this.onsubmit = this.sendAsyncForm.bind(this, this.response, this.onsuccess); // this references a function bound the value of this passed as the 1st arg and the other params.
this.form.addEventListener("submit", this.onsubmit);

// ...
this.form.removeEventListener("submit", this.onsubmit); // and you can reuse that ref to remove the event listener later.
```

**EDIT**

The below explains how you should use the eventListener callback, but it remains some implementation problems in your code, here is a quick review of the AsyncForm class

```js
class AsyncForm {
  // ...

  sendAsyncForm(response, onsuccess, e) { // <- You have to define the event argument here, 
    // or it will be undefined when you use it below. 
    // It is passed automatically by the event handler as the last argument.

    // return (e) => { 
    // ^ You don't need to return a closure since you pass a reference to the function, it will be executed on submit, no need to wrap it.

    e.preventDefault();
    // ...

    $.ajax({
      // ...
      error: (xhr, status) => {
        // if (xhr.status = 422) this.response(xhr.responseText); 
        // I assume you meant this.setResponse ^, since this.response is not a function, 
        // and you used an assignment operator (=) instead of comparison (=== or ==)

        if (xhr.status === /*comparison, not assignment*/ 422) this.setResponse(xhr.responseText);

        else /*???*/ response("<div class='form-error'>Ocurrió un problema al enviar el formulario, disculpe las molestias.</div>"); 
        // I don't understand what you do here ^, where is defined a function response(...) ?
      },
    });
    // }
  }
  // ...

}
```

Comment: onsubmit = this.sendAsyncForm.bind(this, this.response, this.onsuccess);

    prepare() {
        console.log(this.onsubmit);

        this.form.addEventListener("submit", this.onsubmit);
    }

    remove() {
        this.form.removeEventListener("submit", this.onsubmit);
    }

Comment: With the code of the last comment i get the following error: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.

Comment: @DiegoGarcía this was not the only problem in your code. I added a quick review to my answer but I think you'll have a lot more debug to do. (And in your comment you wrote `onsubmit = ...` , it should be `this.onsubmit = ...`